# $L(y)=x^4y''-4x^3y'+6x^2y$, solve $L(y)=\frac{x^6}{(1+x^2)^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve DE $L(y)=\frac{x^6}{(1+x^2)^2}$, where $L(y)=x^4y''-4x^3y'+6x^2y$. Homogenous problem $L(y)=0$ is Euler equation and after substitution $t=\ln{x}$ leads to $L(y)=Cx^2+Dx^3$, but I'm having problem solving $L(y)=\frac{x^6}{(1+x^2)^2}$.
Any help is welcome.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The right side is not in the class suitable for the method of unknown parameters, so you need to go back to variation of coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x^4y''-4x^3y'+6x^2y=x^6f(x)$$
Divide both sides by $x^6$:
$$\dfrac {y''}{x^2}-2\dfrac {y'}{x^3}-2\dfrac {y'}{x^3}+6\dfrac y{x^4}= {f(x)}$$
$$\left (\dfrac {y'}{x^2}-2\dfrac {y}{x^3}\right)'= f(x) $$
$$\left (\dfrac {y}{x^2}\right)''=f(x)$$
Integrate.
$$\left (\dfrac {y}{x^2}\right)''=\dfrac {1}{(x^2+1)^2}$$
$$\left (\dfrac {y}{x^2}\right)'=C_1+\dfrac 12 \arctan x +\dfrac 12 \dfrac {x}{x^2+1}$$
Integrate again.
Note that:
$$\int \arctan x =x \arctan x -\dfrac 12 \ln (x^2+1)+C$$
$$\implies \dfrac {y}{x^2}=C_1x+C_2+\dfrac x2 \arctan x$$
$$\boxed{ {y}{(x)}=C_1x^3+C_2x^2+\dfrac {x^3}2 \arctan x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, divide by $x^2$, then assume a series solution

$$y(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n \implies y'(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^{n-1} \implies y''(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}$$

Substituting these into the ODE, and exploiting the geometric series

$$\frac1{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \quad \text{(assuming $|x|<1$)}$$

to rewrite the right side as a series gives

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^n - 4 \sum_{n=0}^\infty na_nx^n + 6 \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n &= x^2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}nx^{2n}
\end{align*}$$

Condense the left side, and observe that the right side is free of constants or any odd powers of $x$, so $a_0=a_{2n-1}=0$ and we get

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (2n-2)(2n-3)a_{2n}x^{2n} &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n (n-1) x^{2n} \\[2ex]
\implies a_{2n} &= \frac{(-1)^n}{2(2n-3)} & \text{for }n\ge1
\end{align*}$$

Then the particular solution to the nonhomogeneous ODE is

$$\begin{align*}
y(x) &= \frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n-3} x^{2n} \\[1ex]
&= \frac{x^3}2\left(\frac1x + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1} x^{2n+1}\right) \\[1ex]
&= \frac{x^2}2 + \frac{x^3}2 \arctan(x)
\end{align*}$$